# How to set the Image view for each cell with different image iOS.Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am passing List tableitems and then in get cell i am doing this which is generating image view with the last image in each cell.I want all the 4 images in different different cell.the get cell method for this is below:-

```
 public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView   collectionView,   NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableView cell = TableViewView.DequeueReusableCell (CardCellId) as   UITableViewCell;
    foreach(UIImage img in tableitems)
{
    cell.ImageView.Image=img;
}
    return cell;
}
```

here tableitems is my list of UIImages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through your array every time `GetCell` is called which is why only the last image is assigned to your `imageView`.

Try doing `cell.imageView.image = tableitems[indexPath.row]` assuming `tableitems` is `[UIImage]()`